# Столкновение объектов (спрайтов) в 2д игре

Tags: java

Создал классы Target и Bullet. Закинул спрайты через ImageIcon и Image. Как обнаружить столкновение объектов обоих классов?

Comment: Ну для начала надо сделать чтобы они не сталкивались, т.е. хотя бы просто двигались, особенно это актуально для пули ). Ну и собственно при движении, т.е. изменении координат - проверяешь на пересечение хитбоксов.

Comment: Движение я сделал, меня интересует именно столкновение) if (bullet.posX == target.posX & bullet.posY == target.posY){...} не подходит(

Comment: и цель, и пуля - точки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В действительности как и было отмечено в комментарии все таки и сводиться к поиску общих координат для двух сущностей...А как это сделать это уже Ваше дело... Как очень простой пример у вас присутствует поле x100/y100, участники события: объекты-диаметры размером 20(D1,D2). Известны координаты центров участников.Ну а проверкой является определение длинны вектора между двумя центральными точками и сравнение полученной длинны с диаметром объектов как пограничным расстоянием.В свою очередь определение длинны вектора это частное использование теоремы Пифагора.При данном решении обратите внимание что разность координат должна быть абсолютной величиной.Или получите ересь на выходе))Вышеописанное в виде кода:

```
boolean isCross = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(Math.abs(d1.x - d2.x),2)+Math.pow(Math.abs(d1.y - d2.y),2))>20.0d;
```

все вышеперечисленное частный случай который видимо Вам подойдет...
В целом совет на будущее такой: дробите вопрос на частности.Что именно Вы подразумеваете под столкновением?Что общего у участников анализа?и т.д

Данный пример это лишь первый упрощенный шаг в получении информации о некой динамической системе.Что логично второй шаг это определении точек столкновения затем работа с векторами каждого из объектов и.д. Ну и рефакторинг кода затем...

П.С Проводить проверку перед шагом а не после)

Comment: спасибо)) буду пробовать))